# RabbitTemplate.sendAndReceive() method doesn't read message properties

Tags: rabbitmq, client, spring-amqp

When I use this code messageProperties doesn't apply in reply message

```
public class RabbitHelper {
    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    public Message sendAndReceiveMessage() {
        String replyQueue = "reply.topic" + getRandomNumber();
        Message messageRegister = createMessage(replyQueue, message, headers, queryParameters, authData);
        messageRegister.getMessageProperties().setCorrelationId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        return rabbitTemplate.sendAndReceive(queue, messageRegister);
    }
}
```

But if I use just `send()` and then `receive()` - it's ok

How to make read msgProperties in `sendAndReceive()` if I use this method in parallel test suites?

Comment: Would you mind providing more info what is exactly discrepancy? What do you have with a `receive()` that is not available for `sendAndReceive()`?

Comment: Exactly:
- When I use send() - this method check messageProperties and apply them (replyQueue, correlationId)
- When I use sendAndReceive() - this method doesn't check messageProperties (skips them) and apply his OWN replyQueue and correlationId

Comment: That is necessary because the template performs its own correlation internally. If you want to use your own named reply queue, you have to configure a listener container with the template as the listener. But Direct Reply-To is much simpler (and efficient). https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#request-reply

Comment: This question for SpringBootTests.

Unfortunatully, I can't do own RabbitListener as you understand :(

So as I understood, better use send() and receive() in my case, right?

Comment: It has nothing to do with RabbitListener. This is on the client side. You need to explain your use case in much more detail.